# AngularJS ng-change checkbox push $index

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following situation, below its my HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="question in questions">
    <h2>{{question.title}}</h2>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="choice in question.choices track by $index">
            <input ng-change="set(question.answer, choice)" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{$index}}" /> 
            <label for="checkbox-{{$index}}">{{choice}}</label>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I want that when I'm selecting the checkbox, the `$index` to be pushed on `question.answers`, I've tried with `ng-selected`, `ng-change` but no results.

Can someone explain to me what the correct implementation for this is?

Below its my jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18292/

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking.  "$index to be pushed on question.answers" - im not following that.

Comment: so question has a key answers which is an array, i want to push here the index of the selected checkbox

Comment: looks like you got a few answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**So here is what I would do in this situation:**

*Make the choices a list of objects*

Make your choices a list of objects with a choice to display and a Boolean that tracks if it is selected.

```
{
    title:'Title',
    choices: [
        {choice:"choice #1",selected:false},
        {choice:"choice #2",selected:false}, 
        {choice:"choice #3",selected:false}, 
        {choice:"choice #4",selected:false}],
},
```

*Use ng-model on the input field*

You can then use the selected value with the model of the input field instead of trying to push and pull values from a list `onClick`.

This is going to be much cleaner and you personally don't have to keep track if an item is in the list and pop it out instead of push it on for every click.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="choice.selected"/> <label>{{choice.choice}}</label>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/gnu3tLo6)

[Another option that watches the list and builds an Answer list](http://jsfiddle.net/gnu3tLo6/4/)

Granted at this point you would not have a clean list of selected values, but you can easily loop through your questions/choices to generate that list when needed.

Comment: thanks for this but i really need that the booleans or something to be in the question.answers. ive made the ng-model=choice.answers[$index], but its an array of booleans,

Comment: @Hiero may I ask why you need it in questions answers?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Hiero, I added another example that builds a list like you wanted.  I cannot stress enough that this is really expensive and eats a lot of processing that seems very unnecessary.  I would not implement this and opt to build the answers list only when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/18295/

You can use ng-click too

```
<div ng-app>
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="question in questions">
      <h2>{{question.title}}</h2>
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="choice in question.choices track by $index"><input ng-change="set(question.answers, choice)" type="checkbox" id="checkbox-{{$index}}" /> <label for="checkbox-{{$index}}">{{choice}}</label></li>
      </ul>
  </div>
```

Comment: but how to remove when the checkbox its deselected, now if select and deselect it keep adding